# Silverlight not sending byte array to WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I have webcam in a silverlight app. I capture the image and convert it to byte array and send to WCF service. Here is the image capture code:

```
        MessageBox.Show("about to capture");
        cs.CaptureImageAsync();
```

cs is the camera source and is configured correctly (as is the imagecapturecompleted event). On image capture completion, this code executes:

```
        MessageBox.Show("Image Caputred");

        var img = e.Result.ToImage();
        var encoder = new PngEncoder();

        Stream stream = img.ToStreamByExtension("png");

        byte[] file = null;

        if (stream.Length > 512000)
        {
            img = ExtendedImage.Resize(img, 240, new NearestNeighborResizer());
            stream = img.ToStreamByExtension("png");
        }

        if (stream.Length < 512000)
        {
            BinaryReader binary = new BinaryReader(stream);
            file = binary.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            MessageBox.Show("Stream read into file with length: " + file.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("file size too large");
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Process done");

        cs.Stop();

        label1.Content = "and answer is : " + file!= null ? file.Length.ToString() : "ERROR";

        ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        ServiceReference1.ITEM i = new ServiceReference1.ITEM { Image = file };
        obj.DoWorkCompleted += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(obj_DoWorkCompleted);
        obj.DoWorkAsync(i);
```

This is my web.config in the asp.net project that configures the service:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name ="AttendanceSystem.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AttendanceSystem.IService1"/>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

And here is the reference to the service in the silverlight app

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />

            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:48886/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="default" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Fiddler returns the following message on the call to my .svc service file:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Wed, 15 Jan 2014 09:17:26 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close
```

So what is going on?

UPDATE: the service seems to be working without error when I pass a smaller byte array (for example BitConverter.GetBytes(123) but fails when the image is sent which is clearly within the max limits)

Comment: Enable the [wcf tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx) and take a look at the error details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure the binding server-side (`maxReceivedMessageSize` and `reader quotas`)

```xml
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```