# Silverlight: WCF service fails to work when passing larger data within max limit

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

Here is my problem description in full detail:

[Silverlight not sending byte array to WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133527/silverlight-not-sending-byte-array-to-wcf-service?noredirect=1#comment31803002_21133527)

I used a BitConverter.GetBytes(123) to send a small sized byte array and the service worked without any error.

The length of my image byte array is 70K, which is clearly within the max limit of the my WCF service in the problem specification above.

Any ideas why the service is failing for a larger data size that is within the max range?

Comment: Why don't you add this information to that question?

Comment: yea good idea! I'm just a little confused after trying to solve this problem for a while. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are calling your service as a GET that limits the URL to about 2K. You should ensure that the call is done as a POST.